# Express middleware caching

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm trying to implement some caching using express middleware, which seems to work great, but I'm stuck on an infinite loop somewhere.

In my router I have to following route:

```
router.get('/test', [middleware.cache.cache('1 day', true), controllers.test]);
```

middleware.cache.cache looks like this:

```
module.exports.cache = function(time, global) {
    // Do some stuff with the time here

    return function cache(req, res, next) {
        // Keep a copy of the actual send method
        res._send = res.send;

        // Overwrite the res.send function
        res.send = function(obj) {
             console.log('[' + res.statusCode + '] Cache: ' + redisKey);

             // Get the key from redis
             redis.get(redisKey)
                .then(function(result) {
                    result = JSON.parse(result);

                    if(!_.isNull(result)) {
                        console.log('Expired cache found');

                        // Send initial object
                        return res._send(obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Cache found');

                        // Send back cached object
                        return res._send(result.obj);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No data found');

                    storeInRedis(redisKey, obj, time);

                    // Send initial object
                    return res._send(obj);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                console.log(err);

                return res._send(obj);
            });
        };

        next();
    };
};
```

The output I get for this looks like this:

```
[200] Cache: cache_global_test
Cache found
[200] Cache: cache_global_test
Cache found
...
```

So I suspect that when I call res._send(obj), it's actually referring to the original res.send I've just overwritten. Which would of course cause an infinite loop.
But I can't really find any solution for this.

Comment: Check out [`tamper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tamper) and [`express-interceptor`](https://github.com/axiomzen/express-interceptor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`res._send = res.send` doesn't create a copy.

It creates a reference to the function that you're changing later on.

To create a copy use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

Why would you need to 'Overwrite the res.send function' `res.send` function at all?

You can use `next()` inside `redis.get(redisKey).then` to achieve what you want.

I would argue that changing `send` like this may be a dangerous thing, since it's a built-in `express` method and your 'last function' and other developers expect it to behave the way it is described in `express` docs.

It's probably better to add `isCached` and `cache` properties to `res` with cache middleware and then act accordingly in the 'last function', making it explicitly  aware of a possible presence of cached values and cache middleware.

Comment: I need to overwrite it because I want minimal changes in the rest of my program, so for instance, in `controllers.test`, I call `res.status(200).send(...)`.

Comment: Using `next()` inside `redis.get().then` will just continue the middleware chain, which is not something I want, because the last function is the controller that will retrieve items from the database, hence why I'm inserting a middleware.

Comment: Can you make changes to the last function?

Comment: I rather not, the point of using middleware is so that it can be inserted into any route without any other changes.

Comment: try a deep copy trick then `var res._send = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.send));` or https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

Comment: I would argue that changing `send` like this may be a dangerous thing, since it's a built-in `express` method and your 'last function' relies on it to work properly.  It's probably better to add `isCached` and `cache` properties to `res` with the middleware and then act accordingly in the 'last function', making it explicitly  aware of a possible presence of cached values and cache middleware.

Comment: That's true, but that also means adding a lot of custom code in every router callback

Comment: Which can be factored away into separate function(s).  My approach is middleware should modify `req` `res` data, but not `express` methods, unless it is clearly documented.

Comment: That's fair enough, I'll think about a better way to approach this, I agree the current solution isn't the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83451/discussion-between-kyrylkov-and-woutr-be).

Comment: I want to comment how important this answer was. It saved us hours of debugging. I even linked to it in a blog: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0